# how do i convert json object to array without key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following json object

```
{"name":"test","age":"20"}
```

Is it possible to convert it into array as

```
['test','20']
```

How do i achieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Hash#values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values) after parsing the json objects.

```
require 'json'
h = JSON.parse('{"name":"test","age":"20"}')
h.values
# => ["test", "20"]
```

Comment: Ohh!! I missed the JSON object he said.. so we need to use obviously `JSON.parse`. *+1* .

Answer (score 0):

Do as below :

```
 h = {"name" => "test","age" => "20"}
 p h.values # >> ['test','20']
```

As you said json object so you can use [`JSON#parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) or [`JSON#load`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-load)

```
require 'json'
h = JSON.load('{"name":"test","age":"20"}')
p h.values
# => ["test", "20"]
```

Comment: Put the reason of down vote.. to teach me.. please